# Python nested if vs and behviour

Tags: python, algorithm, nested-if

I was solving the **bottom view of a binary tree** question using Python. This code is working.

```
class Solution:
    
    #Function to return a list of nodes visible from the top view 
    #from left to right in Binary Tree.
    def bottomView(self,root):
        dic = {}  
        result = []
        self.helper(root, dic, 0, 0)
        for i in sorted(dic.keys()):
            result.append(dic[i][0])
        return result
                
    def helper(self, root, d, hd, level):
        if root is None:
            return
       
        if hd in d:
            if level >= d[hd][1]:
                d[hd] = (root.data, level)
        else:
            d[hd] = (root.data, level)
             
        self.helper(root.left, d, hd - 1,level + 1)
        self.helper(root.right, d, hd + 1,level + 1)
```

Now, I have a doubt regarding this block of code:

```
if hd in d:
    if level >= d[hd][1]:
        d[hd] = (root.data, level)
```

If I replace it with this code:

```
if hd in d and level >= d[hd][1]:
    d[hd] = (root.data, level)
```

It does not work. As far as I understand the functionality of nested if block, the inner loop condition will be evaluated only if the outer loop condition evaluates to **True** which is similar to what is happening in the **and** statement. But the previous block gives me the correct output while the second block of code just does not work. Why is it so?

Link to problem statement :- https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/bottom-view-of-binary-tree/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `else` Block underneath!

```
if hd in d:
    if level >= d[hd][1]:
        d[hd] = (root.data, level)
else:
    d[hd] = (root.data, level)  # only when hd not there yet!
```

is different from:

```
if hd in d and level >= d[hd][1]:
    d[hd] = (root.data, level)
else:
    d[hd] = (root.data, level)   # also when value for hd meets condition
```

In the first, the else is executed when `hd in d` is not met.
In the second, it is executed more often! Namely when the stronger `hd in d and level >= d[hd][1]` is not met.
Take a close look at the second one: if and else execute the exact same code. That has to be pointless!

If, in fact, you wanted to save some lines here, you could do:

```
if hd not in d or level >= d[hd][1]:
    d[hd] = (root.data, level)
```